I just learned something about mybatis-plus and changed the code written in mybatis to mybatis-plus
Question: MyBatis vs. MyBatis-Plus Implementation问题：MyBatis与MyBatis-Plus实施
I have two implementations of an article management feature using MyBatis and MyBatis-Plus. Below are the respective code snippets for each approach.

Code written using MyBatis1.

    @RestController  
    @RequestMapping("/article")  
    public class ArticleController {
  @Autowired
  private ArticleService articleService;

  @PostMapping  
  public Result add(@RequestBody @Validated Article article) {  
    articleService.add(article);
    return Result.success();  
  }
}

public interface ArticleService {
  void add(Article article);
}

@Service  
public class ArticleServiceImpl extends ServiceImpl<ArticleMapper, Article> implements ArticleService  {
  @Autowired
  private ArticleMapper articleMapper;

  @Override
  public void add(Article article) {
    article.setCreateTime(LocalDateTime.now());  
    article.setUpdateTime(LocalDateTime.now());  

    Map<String, Object> map = ThreadLocalUtil.get();  
    Integer userId = (Integer) map.get("id");  
    article.setCreateUser(userId);  

    articleMapper.add(article);  
  }
}

@Mapper
public interface ArticleMapper {
  @Insert("insert into article(title,content,cover_img,state,category_id,create_user,create_time,update_time) " +  
          "values(#{title},#{content},#{coverImg},#{state},#{categoryId},#{createUser},#{createTime},#{updateTime})")  
  void add(Article article);
}


Code written using MyBatis-Plus2.

@RestController  
@RequestMapping("/article")  
public class ArticleController {

  @Autowired
  private ArticleService articleService;

  @PostMapping  
  public Result add(@RequestBody @Validated Article article) {  
    article.setCreateTime(LocalDateTime.now());  
    article.setUpdateTime(LocalDateTime.now());  

    Map<String, Object> map = ThreadLocalUtil.get();  
    Integer userId = (Integer) map.get("id");  
    article.setCreateUser(userId);  

    articleService.save(article);  

    return Result.success();  
  }
}

public interface ArticleService extends IService<Article> {
}

@Service  
`your text`public class ArticleServiceImpl extends ServiceImpl<ArticleMapper, Article> implements ArticleService {
}

@Mapper
`your text`public interface ArticleMapper extends BaseMapper<Article> {
}

Question
Which implementation is better in terms of code maintainability, performance, and ease of use? Are there any best practices or suggestions for improving the use of MyBatis or MyBatis-Plus in this context?
